# HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.razorpay.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/orders

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, web-development-server

I was developing a social-media/eCommerce web app with Django. I want to add a payment gateway for purchasing products on the website for that I am using 'Razorpay'.
I integrated it which worked fine with my app. But I wanted to store the transaction-related details in a model called 'TransactionDetails'. For that, I call a new function within the view that handles the Razorpay gateway. which creates the instance of the model and saves it.
But for some reason when I call that function I am getting this error, please help me to understand what is happening.

here's my view :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
import razorpay
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from weShare.settings import razorpay_id, razorpay_secret_key
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin, LoginRequiredMixin
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from social.models import *
from social.forms import *

from .models import TransactionDetails
from social.models import UserProfile

client = razorpay.Client(auth=(razorpay_id, razorpay_secret_key))

def home(request, pk):
    rentee = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    renteeName = rentee.user
    renteeLocation = rentee.location

    post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    renter = post.author
    product = post.productName
    subPeriod = post.subscriptionPeriod
    montlycharge = post.productMonthlyCharge
    loc = rentee.location
    order_amount = post.deposite*100

    order_currency = 'INR'
    order_receipt = 'order_rcptid_11'
    notes = {'Shipping address': 'Bommanahalli, Bangalore'}   # OPTIONAL

    payment_order = client.order.create(dict(amount=order_amount, currency=order_currency, payment_capture=1))
    payment_order_id = payment_order['id']

    createTransaction(request, rentee, pk, payment_order_id) # here


    context ={
        'amount' : 100,
        'razorpay_id' : razorpay_id,
        'order_id' : payment_order_id,
        'razorpay_secret_key' : razorpay_secret_key,
        'renter' : renter,
        'product' : product,
        'subPeriod' : subPeriod,
        'montlycharge' : montlycharge,
        'order_amount' : order_amount/100,
    }
    return render(request, 'paymentgateway/index.html', context)

def createTransaction(request, rentee, pk, payment_order_id):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    renter = post.author
    product = post.productName
    subPeriod = post.subscriptionPeriod
    montlycharge = post.productMonthlyCharge
    loc = rentee.location
    order_amount = post.deposite*100

    #Inserting data in TrasactionDetails object
    transaction = TransactionDetails(rentee=request.user, product=product, renter=renter, subPeriod=subPeriod, monthlyCharge=montlycharge, deposite=order_amount, address=loc, order_id=payment_order_id)

    transaction.save()
```

Here's the model.py :

```
from django.db import models
from social.models import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class TransactionDetails(models.Model):
    rentee = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    renter = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    subPeriod = models.IntegerField(default=3)
    monthlyCharge = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    deposite = models.IntegerField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="failed")

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s'%(self.product, self.renter)
```

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be caused by the creation of transaction record. Perhaps the API for razorpay went down and became inaccessible at that time? You might want to check it manually e.g. from your terminal if calling `razorpay.Client` operations will be sucessful.

Comment: no, I am sure the problem occurs when I call createTransaction(request, rentee, pk, payment_order_id) method. The moment I comment that line it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because of your internet connection. Check your internet connection. We are calling razorpay api so we need internet connection. I got this same error when my internet connection gone but when my internet back it working as normal.

Comment: Did you forget to complete your last sentence?

Comment: @S.B Sorry. Thanks for noticing :)